# How to get Windows user privileges information with Lazarus/Free Pascal

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus

Using Lazarus/Free Pascal, how can I get the user privileges of the user running my program (whether he's an Administrator, Regular user, or Guest)?

Comment: So far as I can tell, you need to call `CheckTokenMembership `(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376389(v=vs.85).aspx). Use `DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS` to check for admins,  `DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_GUESTS` for guests and `DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_USERS` for standard users. Group membership appears to be complex to me. Use the sample code in the MSDN link above as your guide. Good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As David says in a comment you can use the [`CheckTokenMembership`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to determine the membership of an user account.

check this sample which runs on FPC and Delphi.

```
program Test;

{$IFDEF FPC}
  {$mode objfpc}{$H+}
{$ELSE}
  {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$ENDIF}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows,
  Classes;

Const
 SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY: TSIDIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5));
 SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID = $00000020;
 DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS     = $00000220;
 DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_USERS      = $00000221;
 DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_GUESTS     = $00000222;
 DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_POWER_USERS= $00000223;

 function CheckTokenMembership(TokenHandle: THandle; SidToCheck: PSID; var IsMember: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall; external advapi32;

 function  UserInGroup(Group :DWORD) : Boolean;
 var
  pIdentifierAuthority :TSIDIdentifierAuthority;
  pSid : Windows.PSID;
  IsMember    : BOOL;
 begin
  pIdentifierAuthority := SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
  Result := AllocateAndInitializeSid(pIdentifierAuthority,2, SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, Group, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, pSid);
  try
    if Result then
      if not CheckTokenMembership(0, pSid, IsMember) then //passing 0 means which the function will be use the token of the calling thread.
         Result:= False
      else
         Result:=IsMember;
  finally
     FreeSid(pSid);
  end;
 end;


begin
 Writeln(Format('Current user is Admin        %s',[BoolToStr(UserInGroup(DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS),True)]));
 Writeln(Format('Current user is Guest        %s',[BoolToStr(UserInGroup(DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_GUESTS),True)]));
 Writeln(Format('Current user is Power User   %s',[BoolToStr(UserInGroup(DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_POWER_USERS),True)]));
 readln;
end.
```

Also you can use the WMI , check the [`Win32_UserAccount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`Win32_GroupUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`Win32_Group`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394151%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) classes.